# Ignore "targeting 'xxx' is not compatible with the project's target" warning

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have created an installer for my project and I included a special .dll file that needs to be copied on the target machine.
The compiler displays the following warning:

File '[filename]' targeting 'Unknown' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

I don't care about the target platform of that dll because I need the file for other purposes. Also, I need to leave this file "untouched" so I cannot change its target platform. So I need a way to ignore this warning.
I tried to accomplish this using #pragma but I can't find the Warning Number for this warning. I tried to find it using the Output window (Build) and also using Show Error Help button with no luck though.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: So your extra dll is x64 and your installer is x86? If it's a warning why is it a problem then? does it break the compilation

Comment: It's not a problem for the compilation, it's just that it looks ugly to have that warning there :)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your project file and add this property group and setting to disable the warning:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I cannot find a way to edit the deployment project file. I have two projects in my solution. One of them is the deployment project. I can edit the other project file but I cannot edit the deployment one.